# Convert device name to model name

Tags: android

As you know, all the Android devices have device names like maguro or crespo.
Is there any data source with projection device name -> model name (e.g. maguro -> Samsung Galaxy Nexus, crespo -> Samsung Nexus S)?

Comment: Are all Android devices made by Samsung these days?

Comment: That's for example. hwu9200 -> Huawei U9200, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [android.os.Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Specifically, you're interested in this:

```
public static final String  MANUFACTURER    The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
public static final String  MODEL           The end-user-visible name for the end product.
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method, but I want to do this on the server-side (my app transfers to the server only device name).

Comment: Your question, as stated, was a bit misleading.  Build yourself a lookup table on the server side.  Of course, you have to know what names the device name translates into, but I don't think you're going to have an easier answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a list of devices (device name, vendor, model, etc) which could be used as a dictionary. It's published as PDF on Google answer page: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131

Direct link to PDF: https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/84AF7DFE379C751BA0F041D5B711E13D87BF